# Trying to make a discord song queue for my bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I've been working on this for at least a few weeks now and I cant get it to work right, I'm trying to make a song queue, when I queue one song it works but when I try queuing a second it stops playing the first restarts the first song then plays through that normally then just stops, doesn't move to the next song. I want to be able to queue songs without interrupting the song that's already playing and then I want it to automatically play the next song once that first one has ended

```
var servers = {};

function play(connection, message) {
    var server = servers[message.guild.id];

    
    const dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(server.queue[0], { filter: 
        "audioonly" }));
    

    server.dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(server.queue[0], { filter: 
    "audioonly" }));


    dispatcher.on('error', console.error);

    server.dispatcher.setVolume(0.2);

    server.dispatcher.on("end", function () {

        server.queue.shift();

    if (server.queue[0]) { play(connection, message);
        playing = true;
    }
    else connection.disconnect().then(()=> {
        playing = false;
    });

});
}



Crashbot.on('message', async message =>{

    //let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    let args = message.content.toString().substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

switch (args[0]) {
 case "play":
        if (!args[1]) {
            message.reply(`You need to put a link after ${PREFIX}play to add a song to the queue`)
            return;
        }
        if (!message.member.voice.channel) {
            message.channel.send("You must be in a voice channel to use this command")
            return;
        }
        if (!servers[message.guild.id]) servers[message.guild.id] = {
            queue: []
        }
        var server = servers[message.guild.id];

        server.queue.push(args[1]);
        if (playing) return;
        console.log(server.queue);

        const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();
    
        play(connection, message);

        if (!message.guild.voiceConnection) message.member.voice.channel.join().then(function (connection) {
                play(connection, message);
        });
        break;

 case "skip":
        var server = servers[message.guild.id];

        if (server.dispatcher) server.dispatcher.end();
        break;
 case "queue":
        message.channel.send(queue);
        break;

 case "stop":
        var server = servers[message.guild.id];

        if (message.guild.voiceConnection) message.guild.voiceConnection.disconnect().then(()=> {
            playing = false;
        });
        break;
}
})
```